# A default localization lang file doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization, default

I am making small fields changes to the register a user form in `register.blade.php` file generated by `artisan make:auth` by changing the ***Name*** input field to ***First Name***

so within `/resources/lang/en/moo.php` I put

```
return [
    'fname' => 'First Name',
    'lname' => 'Last Name'
];
```

and in the blade template

```
<label for="fname">{{ __('fname') }}</label>
```

however the page shows ***fname*** as a result so the localization property is not applied.
Any ideas what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let Laravel know which file for the translation, because you might have another `fname` in another file.

```
{{ __('moo.fname') }}
```